# Creating Array In SourceModule of PyCuda

Tags: arrays, cuda, pycuda

I am a beginner in pyCUDA and trying to make some tests in SourceModule.
With the following code:

```
import pycuda.driver as drv
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule


target = SourceModule(r"""
__device__ void Array_test()
{
    float ** PH = (float **)malloc(50 * sizeof(float *));
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        PH[i]=(float*)malloc(30000*sizeof(float));
    PH[49][29999] = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        free(PH[i]);
    free(PH);  
}

void __global__ f()
{
    Array_test();
}
""")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = drv.Event()
    end = drv.Event()
    start.record()
    test = target.get_function("f")
    test(grid=(1,), block=(2, 1, 1))
    end.record()
    end.synchronize()
    secs = start.time_till(end) * 1e-3
    print(secs)
```

I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cuda_test.py", line 33, in <module>
    end.synchronize()
pycuda._driver.LogicError: cuEventSynchronize failed: an illegal memory access was encountered
PyCUDA WARNING: a clean-up operation failed (dead context maybe?)
cuEventDestroy failed: an illegal memory access was encountered
PyCUDA WARNING: a clean-up operation failed (dead context maybe?)
cuEventDestroy failed: an illegal memory access was encountered
PyCUDA WARNING: a clean-up operation failed (dead context maybe?)
cuModuleUnload failed: an illegal memory access was encountered
```

Is this caused by my misuse of malloc in GPU programming and how can I solve it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dynamically allocated arrays allocated in kernel code use a runtime heap which you must ensure is sized correctly, otherwise you will run out of memory. The kernel `malloc` returns `NULL` if the allocation fails, you can test for that to see if that is the problem. You can [change the limit](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/driver.html#pycuda.driver.Context.set_limit) if that is the case

Comment: 2*50*30000*4 = 12MB which exceeds the 8MB default limit.